# Webscraping Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

Hi I'm trying to scrape data from a website and it worked fine for quite some time and now I get this error message: "*'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'*" and it's not scraping any data anymore.
They must have changed something on the website but I can't figure out what.

The Error occourse in the line: "*data_page = soup_page.find('script', text=r_page).text*"

That's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import time
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import json

for seite in range(1):
    
    print("Loop " + str(seite) + " startet.")
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    l=[]

    try:
        
        page = ("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/radius/neubauwohnung-kaufen?centerofsearchaddress=Krefeld;47799;Grenzstra%C3%9Fe;;;Bockum&geocoordinates=51.33798;6.58608;1.0&enteredFrom=result_list")
        print(page)

        res_page = requests.get(page)
        soup_page = bs(res_page.content, 'lxml')
        r_page = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
        data_page = soup_page.find('script', text=r_page).text
        script_page = r_page.findall(data_page)[0].rstrip(',')
        results_page = json.loads(script_page)

        for item in results_page['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries'][0]['resultlistEntry']:
            l.append(item['@id'])
            if 'similarObjects' in item:
                for i in item['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject']:
                    if isinstance(i,dict):
                        l.append(i['@id'])
                    elif i == '@id':
                        l.append(item['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject'][i])
        l = list(set(l))
```

Comment: the r_page line is where the problem is, it's not finding anything.  Probably a good idea to print soup_page and make sure 'resultListModel' is in there, because it probably isn't.  That should give you a hint as to why this is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returns CAPTCHA page if you don's specify `User-Agent` and `Accept-Language` HTTP headers:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}

for seite in range(1):    
    print("Loop " + str(seite) + " startet.")
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    l=[]

    page = ("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/radius/neubauwohnung-kaufen?centerofsearchaddress=Krefeld;47799;Grenzstra%C3%9Fe;;;Bockum&geocoordinates=51.33798;6.58608;1.0&enteredFrom=result_list")
    res_page = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
    soup_page = BeautifulSoup(res_page.content, 'lxml')
    r_page = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
    data_page = soup_page.find('script', text=r_page).string
    script_page = r_page.findall(data_page)[0].rstrip(',')
    results_page = json.loads(script_page)

    for item in results_page['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries']:
        item = item['resultlistEntry']
        l.append(item['@id'])
        if 'similarObjects' in item:
            for i in item['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject']:
                if isinstance(i,dict):
                    l.append(i['@id'])
                elif i == '@id':
                    l.append(item['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject'][i])
    l = list(set(l))

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['119256589', '119215242', '119254488', '119256425', '119254296', '119256175', '119240835']
```